# How to animate the entry and deletion of characters on UITextField?

Tags: ios, animation, uitextfield, user-input, user-experience

I would like to animate the user entry and deletion **character by character** in **UITextField**. For example, I want each character bounce in and bounce out when user is entering or deleting them.

Is there a formal way to do that by overriding some methods in UITextField ? Or I need to do a trick by using another UILabel or somehow, do you have an idea ?

Thanks in advance.